# Jquery radio prop not updated

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a weird one.

I have the below code where I select a radio element and try to set it as disabled.

```
let radio = element.find('input[type="radio"]');
  // radio.remove();
  radio.prop("disabled", true);
```

If I use the remove() method, the element gets removed.
However, when I try to set the "disabled" prop to true, it just doesn't work.
Don't see the HTML updating either.

I've tried `radio.attr("disabled", true);` and `radio.attr("disabled",'disabled');`with no luck as well.

Any idea why this is happening?

Using jQuery v3.5.1.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With jquery, it is easy to do as follows, means you are in right direction:

```
element.find('input[type="radio"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$('input[type="radio"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

You need to verify what you have written in element. Can you write in detail how did you have declared `element`?